# Convert nested text file to JSON object using Python

Tags: python, json

Wondering if there's a way to convert a nested txt file that is almost in json format but just needs "" and :'s to be inserted.
Sample txt file

```
interfaces {
    ethernet eth0 {
        address 11.1.1.1/30
        description eth1
    }
    ethernet eth1 {
        address someothervalue
        description eth2
    }
service {
   snmp {
      key value
   }
}
```

converted would be:

```
{
    "interfaces" {
        "ethernet eth0" {
            "address" : "11.1.1.1/30",
            "description" : "eth1"
        },
        "ethernet eth1" {
            "address" : "someothervalue",
            "description" : "eth2"
        }
    "service" {
       "snmp" {
          "key" : "value"
       }
    }

}
```

Not sure how to start, do I just need to loop through each line and detect if it's key:value pair or start of another nested dictionary. Then add , to the last line if there's another key:value pair?

Comment: You should write a custom parser specifically for this format, not try to somehow make it JSON just because it’s vaguely reminiscent of it.

Comment: @deceze I was starting to try to create a custom parser to change the format but was struggling. There's quiet a couple of steps, just trying to get all the rules of JSON written down then guess it's about working out a way to program it.
I've done the add "{ \n" to the start and } to the end. But trying to work out if the next line needs a comma depends on lines above and below. I'm not the most experienced so was wondering if someone else has any experience with writing something like this.

Comment: Exactly, you *don't* want to be dealing with *two* formats' syntax. Write a parser using, for example, https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/, to parse the data into a Python data structure of lists and dicts. You can then easily encode it to JSON from there if you actually need to have it in JSON format for some other reason.